# How to create a non-reusable UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

**EDIT: It seems I wasn't completely clear in my meaning of "small/fixed number of cells". What I mean is that the *number* of cells is unchanging (there is always only 10 cells). *However*, the cells' contents are very dynamic. I have a complex UITableViewCell class to handle this, and it's difficult for me to "capture" the exact state of every element and variable at a given time for the "reusing" to work correctly.**

I know it's highly frowned upon... but I would like to create UITableViewCells that are not reusable. The reason I have decided on this is because I only need a small/fixed number of cells (10 to be exact), and they are pretty complex, so I feel like having to capture their various states before they are reused, and then resetting these states when each cell is shown, would be excessively tedious, especially since memory doesn't seem like it will be an issue with only ten *non*-reusable cells.

However, I am confused how to do this (there is very limited online resources on achieving this unorthodox task). As a simplified test, I tried to simply create an instance of my CustomTableViewCell in the `cellForRowAt` data source method, but the cell appears completely blank. It does not appear that any of the IBOutlets were established prior to the cell being displayed (I posted a `print()` statement in the cell's `awakeFromNib()` method and it was never called).

Does anyone know what steps I am missing and/or doing incorrectly?

For reference, here is my table view data source's `cellForRowAt` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  
  // Assuming for the sake of the argument that there is only one row (so only one cell needed)...  
  let cell = CustomTableViewCell()
  return cell

}
```

I have also tried creating the cell with `let cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "customCell")` but this didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated--thanks!

Comment: If the cells are *fixed* use static cells with outlets.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well actually my table doesn't _show_ a fixed number of cells (it is variable between one and ten). But the cells that are shown are created beforehand and do not change, so in that sense they are _fixed_. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you simply instantiate an instance of a class then none of the outlets will be connected, since the connection happens during the process of loading the cell from a storyboard or nib file. You didn't do this, so of course the cell was never "awakeFromNib". You could register your cells with different reuse identifiers but it is nearly always better to simply use the tableview with reusable cells.

Comment: *t's difficult for me to "capture" the exact state of every element and variable at a given time for the "reusing" to work correctly.* Why? What's so difficult? You need a specific data model, then modify the model and reload the row(s). In `cellForRow` set all UI elements to a defined state. If you have UI elements in the cell which allow user interaction use callback closures to update the model. Not reusing the cells is the worse and less efficient choice.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes that is what I am missing! I didn't understand that concept. Can you explain how to do that? If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. btw, I would be loading it from a storyboard, not a nib file.

Comment: @vadian Okay you are probably right, but for now I'm just going to stick with my (probably wrong) approach since that's how it is coded right now. However, I will look into doing the way you suggested. My main hesitancy with that method is that I have a ton of IBOutlets that have various states (ie. alpha values changing constantly etc.), and I would have to refactor my whole project to transfer the info to an independent model. Right now it's all contained within the actual cell (which poses a huge problem when reusing). Though now I am noticing my approach is flawed.

Comment: @vadian Can you explain the callback closures concept? For example, let's say I have two states for a UILabel, `showing` and `notShowing`. `showing` means `alpha=1.0` and `label.text = "showing"`, while `notShowing` means `alpha = 0.5` and `label.text="Not Showing"`. Do I just have two functions that I call depending on the state of the cell (like `func showLabel()` and func `hideLabel`)?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I might have figured it out myself... Looks like you can put callback functions as the value of enum states, so that basically answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

For making your cell static, once you have to create tableViewController go for attribute inspector make the content type from dynamic to static. so you can fix the number of cells to particular number(mentioned below in 1st and 2nd picture )..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfcRm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H39f1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, but you might try to call the **override func prepareForReuse()** in your **CustomTableViewCell()**.
For example, if you want to add a switch in a table view, to avoid that the  reusable cell will mess all switches in your list, you can do like this :

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    // declare the switch with the default state
    mySwitch.isOn = false
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little clarification ...

Just because you use a **reusable cell** doesn't mean you have to do anything "dynamic" to it.

Assuming you are designing your cells in Storyboard, you may have something like this:

[image]

I've designed 5 "complex static" cells. They look exactly how I want them displayed, so no custom cell classes or `@IBOutlet` connections.

All I've done is given each one a different `identifier` ... in this case, I used "type1" / "type2" / "type3" / "type4" / "type5".

Now, a simple controller class:

```
class RowTypesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var theData: [Int] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        theData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let id: String = "type\(theData[indexPath.row])"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: id, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Notice that in `cellForRowAt` I use the data source value to generate a reuse identifier:

```
let id: String = "type\(theData[indexPath.row])"
```

and it loads (dequeues) the correct "static" cell, and I get this output:

[image]

If I change my data source array to:

```
theData = [1, 3, 4]
```

I get this:

[image]

Using `theData = [5, 4]`:

[image]

and using `theData = [4, 3, 5, 1, 2]`:

[image]

As you can see, the cells are "static" but I can display only the ones I want, in the order I want.

If you are designing your cells in `xib` files, add this to `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "type1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "type1")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "type2", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "type2")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "type3", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "type3")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "type4", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "type4")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "type5", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "type5")
```

Obviously, replace the "type" strings with strings that make sense to your code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. However, I don't think I was entirely clear what I meant by "fixed". If you could see my EDIT to my question, hopefully it will clarify things. Thank you!

Comment: @Eric33187 - hmmm... the edit seems to be a very different question. What do you mean by *"capture" the exact state of every element*? You should be managing your data and then setting that data in your cell in `cellForRowAt`. If you have user-interaction UI elements in your cell(s), you should be updating your data when something changes so those changes will "persist" the next time the cell is used.

Comment: Yes, it has become apparent to me that I should be doing as you have suggested. If you have the time, could you take a look at my [new stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66198963/how-to-store-changes-to-user-interaction-uielements-occurring-within-uitableview) which asks how to accomplish this?