# How to store changes to user-interaction UIelements occurring within UITableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have recently become aware that when using a UITableView, I should be managing all my cells' data outside of the actual cell objects (to "persist" my data since cells are reused). Then, when I need to provide a cell to my tableview in my `cellForRowAt` method, I simply set that "persisted" data to my reused cell.

However, I am confused specifically on how to store changes in user-interaction UIelements in my cells? (For example, if a UILabel's alpha value changes from a default 1.0 to a new value of 0.5)

Here are a couple possible ideas I've had (which I'm not convinced are correct, so any critiques or suggestions are welcome):

1. Replicate each IBOutlet variable of the cell entirely in the cell's data model (meaning I would have a UILabel in the UITableViewCell, and a persisted copy in my CellModel). Then I can just copy these entire variables back to the cell in the `cellForRowAt` method. However, this seems kind of redundant and a waste of memory.
2. Just record the specific change in my cell' model. For example, if an alpha value of a UILabel changes, just record that specific new alpha value, not the whole UILabel. However, the problem/confusion I'm seeing with this is that it seems like I might be recording a lot of things for just one element (if more than just an alpha changes for a particular element). I am also confused on how I should actually implement this (so maybe this could be a lot easier than I'm visualizing?).

Appreciate the guidance

ps. I use storyboard

Comment: **Never** use 1. As I said in your previous question use 2. and implement callback closures to update the model. Easier is not necessarily more efficient and more reliable. Add a concrete example to your question what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: The question is *why is the alpha 0.5?*. That should be related to some aspect of your data model. That is what you are storing and that is what you use in `cellForRow`.

Comment: Light bulb  . I’m understanding now, thank you both

Comment: @vadian can you please explain how I could implement the callback closure? I'm very confused on how to do that...

Comment: For example please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should never be a case where you would need to store `UITableViewCell` UI variable state inside cell data model, you can do it tho, but it is highly discouraged.

Usually your UI state (not only `UITableViewCell`s, any UI element) depends on some data model it represents. So, in your case, data model of a cell could have a boolean/enum or whatever else to represent a state of a cell and you could compose your `UITableViewCell`'s depending on their data model states.

Comment: Aha! Light bulb . Makes so much more sense now